# Translation workbench and Screen Flow version

Tags: visual-workflow, translation, translation-workbench, screen-flow

I'm working on translating the screen components of version 1 of my flow using translation workbench.

When I save the flow as a new version the translations don't make it to the new one i.e. it looses the translations.

What can I do in order to apply my translations from version 1 to 2?

Answer (score 0):

You have to select Flow Version to 2 under translate and save your changes.